# Removing duplicates based on a condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When removing duplicates, can I keep those rows that match a condition? Instead of doing:

```
df.remove_duplicates(subset=['x','y'], keep='first']
```

do:

```
df.remove_duplicates(subset=['x','y'], keep=df.loc[df[column]=='String'])
```

Suppose I have a df like:

```
A  B

1  'Hi'
1  'Bye'
```

Keep the rows with 'Hi'. I want to do it this way because it would be more handful since I am going to introduce multiple conditions in the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with invert mask and chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` by condition:

```
df['mask'] = ~df.duplicated(subset=['A','B']) & (df['B']=='Hi')
print (df)
   A    B   mask
0  1   Hi   True
1  1  Bye  False
2  1   Hi  False
3  1  Bye  False
```

Tested with duplciated index and working perfectly:

```
df.index = [0] * 4

df['mask'] = ~df.duplicated(subset=['A','B']) & (df['B']=='Hi')
print (df)
   A    B   mask
0  1   Hi   True
0  1  Bye  False
0  1   Hi  False
0  1  Bye  False
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it raises: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @alb - how looks your real code? It is weird error.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo from my part. It works perfectly but it resets the runtime on Colab lol. Do you know how to avoid crashing?

Comment: @alb - Hard question, it crash because large Dataframe? Or because some oldier version?

Comment: because of large dataframe (~1M).  It'd be interesting if you could say to Colab not to use the maximum amount of resources available even if the process lasts much longer.

Comment: @alb - Unfortuantely I have no experience with Colab, so no idea :(